# I have a datetime, and i need to see if this datetime is between two other times

Tags: mysql, datetime

In my MySQL table , I have two time datatype columns storing a `starttime` value( (01:00:00) (call it B) and an `endtime` value (07:00:00) (call it C) for a record.

In my form, I collect a date and time from user and convert this to a datetime in my code (call it A), then in mySQL query I query for all records where A is between `B` and `C`

```
Select * from targetTBL where #pickupdatetime# between B and C
```

the problem is that when I do a dump of the time values B,C,  they show up as 1970-01-01 01:00:00 and 1970-01-01 07:00:00

Ideally, I would like to compare just the time portion.
Ex.

```
A = 2014-03-18 07:00:00
```

where 07:00:00 between 01:00:00 and 07:00:00

instead of 
where `2014-03-18 07:00:00 between 1970-01-01 01:00:00 and 1970-01-01 07:00:00`

but when I do the date math using compare, I think that the date arithmetic is off because of the date part.

Is it possible to do something like this in a query using just the time part?

```
where 07:00:00 between 01:00:00 and 07:00:00
```

I am getting a result , I just don't trust it...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
WHERE timevalue BETWEEN time(field1) AND time(field2)
```

MySQL has a LARGE number of date/time-specific functions just for this sort of thing: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: I think time() function returns a string, so cannot do date math??

Comment: No. Read the man page. it returns a time VALUE, which mysql politely presents as a string. it's a perfectly normal time value internally and can be used for any time-based math you want.

Comment: ok, that explains why I am getting a value...  what about the date that gets appended to the time part? 1970-01-01.   I am programming in coldfusion, and when I do a dump of the value in the table, it appears as 1970-01-01 01:00:00 and 1970-01-01 07:00:00.  Will this muck up my results?

Comment: a time value has no date component, so if it gets "upscaled" to a full date, mysql picks out the epoch date, Jan 1/1970, since that's "time 0"

Comment: dump from query:{ts '1970-01-01 23:59:59'}  4  2.6  fkl Taxi corp  {ts '1970-01-01 19:00:00'}

Comment: I will test this and report my findings

Comment: This seems to have done the trick...  AND  "#TimeFormat(thepickupdatetime, 'HH:mm:ss')#" between Time(starttime_tues) and 
        Time(endtime_tues)

Comment: this turned my value A to an equal time   where 1970-01-01 01:00:00 between 1970-01-01 01:00:00 and 1970-01-01 07:00:00.    Should the older time be first?

Comment: I am getting correct values now.  Thanks for the nudge in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
Select * from targetTBL where hour(#pickupdatetime#) between B and C
```